# fetch data from array is very slow while display

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

This is my code:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']) & !empty($_POST['appid'])) {

        $app = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['appid']);

        //database parameters

        $conp = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database) or die('error in connection' . mysqli_error());

        //actual data for appid's

        $appsi = mysqli_query($conp, "SELECT distinct package_name FROM `user_app` where `app_id` = '$app'");

        $all = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($appsi)) {

        $all[] = $row["package_name"]; // array problem

    }


    foreach ($all as $value) {

        $install = mysqli_query($conp, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS installs from `install` where package_name = '$value'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($install);
        $data[] =  '<b>' .$row["installs"] . '</b>';


        $reg = mysqli_query($conp, "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `imei_num` ) AS reg FROM `user_app` WHERE package_name = '$value'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reg);

$regd[] =  '<b>' .$row["reg"] . '</b>';

    }



 }

    mysqli_close($conp);

    ?>



    <html>
    <head>

        <title>script</title>

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <span style="text-align: center"><h1>Beta</h1></span>


        <form name="query" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

        <p>Enter Application-Specific Id:</p> 

        <select name='appid'>

        <?php 

        $conp = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database) or die('error in connection' . mysqli_error());

        $getid = mysqli_query($conp, "SELECT distinct `app_id`, `appidt` from `user_app` group by `app_id`") or die('get data failed' . mysqli_error());

            while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getid)) != null)  {

                echo "<option value = '{$row['app_id']}' selected = 'selected'";

                    if ($selected == $row['app_id']) {

                        echo "selected = 'selected'";

                    }

                echo ">{$row['appidt']}</option>";
            }

    mysqli_close($conp);

    ?>

        </select>



        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" /></p>

        </form>

        <div>

            <p><?php echo '<br />' .'<b>'. 'Application Id : '. $app . '</b>'; ?> </p>
            <hr />
            <table border=2px width=100%>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>App Packages</b></th>
                    <th><b>Registrations</b></th>
                    <th><b>Installs</b></th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo implode("<br><br>", $all); ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo implode("<br><br>", $regd); ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo implode("<br><br>", $data); ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <p><?php echo "$name"; ?></p>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am fetching my all package names in an array: all[], packages might  be 10 or 20 in ranges, after this i want all downloads corresponding  to packages which is on another table name `downloads` and packages on  another table `app_packages`.

I can't uses join because package table contain specific packages but downloads contain many number of  downloads corresponding to packages.

So, i put all packages in all[] and use them in foreach loop name $value, now i get all installs per packages and i can display it via implode function. But in my frontend, when i select an appid from dropdown as you can see, it will take huge time to retrieve downloads  number per packages. This is not what i want to display because it is  very time taking.

Please see this problem, and if i missing something  in explanation then i apologize, prompt me and i mention it.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

Using query in loop is a bad idea. that is the reason you are geting slow result. it touches database on each iteration. you can do this with subquery or join as alternative way.

Comment: i'll try to use joins and subquery but it is not work, i am using like select count(*) from downloads where package_name in (select package_name from user_app); Join is not work since user_app have only limited packages and downloads have several entries of packages, so on condition is not working on behalf of id's